# How to fetch data in one row using case condition

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, case, distinct

I have two tables and i wanted data should come in specific format.

My query

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT ur.suid,
(CASE WHEN ur.sceneID = '1' THEN ur.data ELSE 0 END) AS Scenario1data, 
(CASE WHEN ur.sceneID = '1' THEN ss.score ELSE 0 END) AS Scenario1score, 
(CASE WHEN ur.sceneID = '2' THEN ur.data ELSE 0 END) AS Scenario2,
(CASE WHEN ur.sceneID = '3' THEN ur.data ELSE 0 END) AS Scenario3, 
(CASE WHEN ur.sceneID = '4' THEN ur.data ELSE 0 END) AS Scenario4  
FROM tbluserresults AS ur LEFT JOIN tbluserscenescores AS ss ON ss.suid = ur.suid;
```

Result i wanted

```
suid    Scenario1data   Scenario1score  Scenario2   Scenario3   Scenario4
1        'abc show1'           334      abc show2    abc show3 abc show 4
2           0              0                0   0.
```

Check my [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22bfd/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably other better ways to do this, but I believe the following does what you want

```
SELECT results.suid as suid,
 (CASE WHEN results.Scenario1data IS NOT NULL THEN results.Scenario1data ELSE 0 END) AS Scenario1data,
 (CASE WHEN results.Scenario1score IS NOT NULL THEN results.Scenario1score ELSE 0 END) AS Scenario1score,
 (CASE WHEN results.Scenario2 IS NOT NULL THEN results.Scenario2 ELSE 0 END) AS Scenario2,
 (CASE WHEN results.Scenario3 IS NOT NULL THEN results.Scenario3 ELSE 0 END) AS Scenario3,
 (CASE WHEN results.Scenario4 IS NOT NULL THEN results.Scenario4 ELSE 0 END) AS Scenario4
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT(suid), @suid:= suid,
  (SELECT ur.data FROM tbluserresults ur WHERE ur.suid = @suid AND ur.sceneID = '1') AS Scenario1data,
  (SELECT ss.score FROM tbluserscenescores ss WHERE ss.suid = @suid AND ss.sceneID = '1') AS Scenario1score,
  (SELECT ur.data FROM tbluserresults ur WHERE ur.suid = @suid AND ur.sceneID = '2') AS Scenario2,
  (SELECT ur.data FROM tbluserresults ur WHERE ur.suid = @suid AND ur.sceneID = '3') AS Scenario3,
  (SELECT ur.data FROM tbluserresults ur WHERE ur.suid = @suid AND ur.sceneID = '4') AS Scenario4
FROM tbluserscenescores) AS results
```

Comment: can u explain me what u had done? and flow of thinking

Comment: The outer select is simply to replace null with 0 (as in your example). If you don't mind having null then you can omit it. The inner select collects the data you want for each column, depending on the scene ID. I assumed here that you know a priori the possible scene IDs, i.e. 1-4. For each record in tbluserresults, related record from tbluserscenescores is retrieved with the same id and scene ID. Note that this should take some time if you have lots of data. Does the query get you the results you want?

Comment: thanks ..yes i got result from your query. i am not interested in outer select stmt. i want to know why u take 1 `DISTINCT(suid), @suid:= suid,` ?. 2 what is `@` logic?

Comment: By @suid:= suid, you store the suid of the current record into a temp variable called suid. This allows you to maintain the current value of suid and call it afterwards when you try to fill each column. By '@suid', you reference this variable.

Comment: when i m fire this query i get o records ..`  SELECT ur.data FROM tbluserresults ur WHERE ur.suid = @suid AND ur.sceneID = '1'` why?
`

Comment: Are you trying to execute this as standalone query? If yes you'll get no results, since the temporal variable @suid  is not set. You need to execute the query as a whole or replace the temp variable with an actual value in order to execute it as standalone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88762/discussion-between-prashant-tapase-and-dchar).